# JQuery plugin for showing daily events in a bar chart

Tags: jquery, calendar

Are there any JQuery plugins that can show events in single, horizontally oriented time bars  that has draggable properties? Something like a gantt chart except that each bar can have one or more events/items.

The plugins that I have found usually only deals with day and month units. I am looking for a plugin that can deal with minutes and hour units.

EDIT:

Something like the picture in [this](http://www.webappers.com/2010/06/08/wdcalendar-jquery-based-google-calendar-clone/) but only that the "columns" are horizontally oriented(x axis as time) and that each "column" does not represent a date but a type of event

Comment: What do you mean by "single" in the first sentence?  Especially if you're saying "each bar can have one or more events/items"